# Split dataframe into chunks of unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe of two groups (`A` and `B`) and within those groups, 6 subgroups (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f`). Example data below:

```
index   group    subgroup    value
0       A        a           1
1       A        b           1
2       A        c           1
3       A        d           1
4       A        e           1
5       A        f           1
6       B        a           1
7       B        b           1
8       B        c           1
9       B        d           1
10      B        e           1
11      B        f           1
...     ...      ...         ...
```

While I've only listed 12 rows here, there are 300 rows in the real dataset. I'm trying to randomly split the dataframe into 50 batches of 6 values. Importantly, each batch should have 1 of each subgroup and an approximately equal distribution of group.

Desired output:

```
index   group    subgroup    batch
0       A        a           1
1       A        b           1
2       A        c           1
3       B        d           1
4       B        e           1
5       B        f           1
6       A        d           2
7       A        e           2
8       A        f           2
9       B        a           2
10      B        b           2
11      B        c           2
...     ...      ...         ...
```

In my dataset, there are 150 `A`'s and 150 `B`'s, but unfortunately, there's not an equal number of subgroups (e.g., I have something like 25 `a`s, 27 `b`s, 23 `c`s, etc. contained with `A`) So it would be preferred if batches 1-48 contained unique subgroups (i.e., 1 of each a-f), but then batches 49 and 50 would have the leftovers that didn't split into an equal distribution — I'll need to somehow randomize these by hand after the fact! The most important thing is that there is one of each subgroup within a batch, but it is less important that there is exactly 3 `A`s and 3 `B`s in a batch. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution picks out exactly one element from each `subgroup` for batch 1-48. Batch 49-50 are picked randomly. The numbers from `A`s and `B`s are not considered.

## Logic

1. Shuffle each subgroup by performing **random permutation on the index of each subgroup**.
2. The first elements from each subgroup form the first batch, the second elements form the second batch, etc.

## Code

```
# data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"group": ["A"]*150 + ["B"]*150,
     "subgroup": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"] * 48 + ["a", "b"]*3 + ["c", "d"]*2 + ["e", "f"],
     "value": range(0, 3000, 10)}
)
df.index.name = "index"

# length parameters
subgroups = df["subgroup"].unique()  # np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
l = len(subgroups)  # 6
m = 48  # number of regular batches
n = int(len(df) / l)  # 300/6=50

# storage
arr = np.zeros((m, l))  # for batch 1-48
ls_rest = []  # for batch 49-50

# shuffle
for i, subgroup in enumerate(subgroups):
    perm = np.random.permutation(df.index[df["subgroup"] == subgroup])
    arr[:, i] = perm[:m]  # for regular batches
    ls_rest += list(perm[m:])  # for the rest

# assign batch 1-48
df["batch"] = 0
for i in range(m):
    df.loc[arr[i,:], "batch"] = i+1

# assign batch 49-50
for i in range(n-m):
    df.loc[ls_rest[i*l:(i+1)*l], "batch"] = m+1+i

# sorting is omitted
```

## Output

### regular batches

One can see that there is indeed one element per subgroup within each batch.

```
print(df.sort_values(["batch", "subgroup"]).head(13))

      group subgroup  value  batch
index                             
48        A        a    480      1
13        A        b    130      1
134       A        c   1340      1
171       B        d   1710      1
262       B        e   2620      1
5         A        f     50      1
240       B        a   2400      2
291       B        b   2910      2
152       B        c   1520      2
93        A        d    930      2
136       A        e   1360      2
59        A        f    590      2
24        A        a    240      3
```

### the rest

```
print(df.sort_values(["batch", "subgroup"]).tail(13))

      group subgroup  value  batch
index                             
29        A        f    290     48
120       A        a   1200     49
222       B        a   2220     49
276       B        a   2760     49
61        A        b    610     49
133       A        b   1330     49
289       B        b   2890     49
98        A        c    980     50
206       B        c   2060     50
45        A        d    450     50
295       B        d   2950     50
166       B        e   1660     50
233       B        f   2330     50
```

Comment: — thank you for your well commented code! This works great for shuffling unique subgroups into batches, but could you perhaps give advice on how I can get an approximately equal distribution of `group` in each batch?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of a way for now, otherwise I'd have done it already. Every strategy I could think of was unable to prevent extreme cases from happening. E.g., (1) early exhaust of a certain `(group, subgroup)` or (2) too many unpicked entries in a certain `subgroup` remain after all other `subgroups` are exhausted. I am not even sure whether this could be done in polynomial time. Therefore I went for the minimum requirement first.